# How can I get current audio URL playing inside my app from WKWebView?

Tags: ios, audio, wkwebview, mpmusicplayercontroller, mpnowplayinginfocenter

I have a **WKWebView** and I am checking if audio is playing using

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] isOtherAudioPlaying]
```

I tried to get some information about it using :

```
  [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter] nowPlayingInfo]
```

but it was nil.

Then I tried:

```
 [[MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer] nowPlayingItem]
```

and it was also nil.

How can I get URL of current playing audio?

Comment: this answer is working for you ?

Comment: can you help me for this question @kallahir https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377677/how-to-detect-avplayer-and-get-url-of-current-video-from-wkwebview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subscribe on notification :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playerItemBecameCurrent:)
                                             name:@"AVPlayerItemBecameCurrentNotification"
                                           object:nil];
```

And then do this inside method `playerItemBecameCurrent`

```
-(void)playerItemBecameCurrent:(NSNotification*)notification {
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [notification object];
if(playerItem == nil) return;
// Break down the AVPlayerItem to get to the path
AVURLAsset *asset = (AVURLAsset*)[playerItem asset];
NSURL *url = [asset URL];
NSString *path = [url absoluteString];}
```

Comment: this solution isn't work for me can you guide me how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

As you can already detect when the audio is being played I think that the solution for you would be implementing **decidePolicyForNavigationAction** method from the **WKNavigationDelegate**.

You can combine the information provided by this delegate method that will be called whenever a link is clicked associated with the audio detection the you have already done.

Comment: No, this is not working for audio-buttons.When you klick them this method is not calling.

Comment: Please share a little bit more information of exactly what you're trying to do, because I think that I misunderstood what you're trying to do.

Comment: Well.I am trying to make kind of file-downloader using built-in WKWebView.User clicks on a button to play a song or  a video and I show him alert asking if he wants to download this audio or video.I gave more information in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42459538/method-decidepolicyfornavigationaction-is-not-called-some-times and i gave a link for the app that does this functionality

Comment: Sorry I wouldn't know how to help you in the cenario described.

Comment: If you could please share it here, it would be awesome.

Comment: I will in a few hours